# Enter key multi-functionality VB2010

Tags: vb.net

So I have a multi-tab calculator that I'm working on, and I'm trying to make the enter key focus the next text box and run the calculations on the button press, to function something like a typical spreadsheet might when running calculations on cells.

The accept button is assigned on form load, and again on tab changes, and on it's own works swimmingly.

```
Private Sub CalcTabs_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles CalcTabs.SelectedIndexChanged
    If CalcTabs.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
        AcceptButton = calcButton
    ElseIf CalcTabs.SelectedIndex = 1 Then
        AcceptButton = calcButtonBuy
    End If
```

I've coded the keystroke events in the input boxes for no mouse navigation

```
Private Sub priceTritBox_KeyDown(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles priceTritBox.KeyDown
    If e.KeyData = (Keys.Return) Then
        e.SuppressKeyPress = True
        pricePyerBox.Focus()
    End If
    If e.KeyData = Keys.Up Then
        e.SuppressKeyPress = True
        npcStandingBox.Focus()
    End If
    If e.KeyData = (Keys.Down) Then
        e.SuppressKeyPress = True
        pricePyerBox.Focus()
    End If
End Sub
```

I have opted to use .focus() rather than tabindex, because when using tabindex I cannot seem to keep the cursor in the proper text boxes after tabbing through the allotted 8 boxes.  (There are 56 text boxes on this tab of the form, and only 8 need to be editable.  So I guess what I'm saying is when i'm using tabindex it will cycle through the boxes once and then stop on the button.  This is despite my best efforts to remove all but the 8 input boxes from the tabindex)

I guess I felt I should clarify above because if it has something to do with my problem, then I've got another can of worms to deal with.  Anyhow, is there some way to make these two snippets exist in the same code and function?  If I add the acceptButton to the form in any way, it kills the KeyDown functionality of the enter key for the input boxes.

Sorry if this is confusing.  tl:dr, how do I make enter key press activate the button and navigate the form at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
Private Sub OnKeyDownHandler(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As KeyEventArgs)
    If (e.Key = Key.Return) Then
        AcceptButton.Click()
    End If

    Me.tabcontrolname.SelectedTab = nameofthetab
End Sub
```